# protege set data range expression for a data properties

Tags: range, ontology, protege, protege4, manchester-syntax

I have a data properties ***hasCode*** that can assume one of this values:

- "1i"
- "2i"
- "3i"
- "4i"

What is the expression that I have to write for get this restriction?
[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{"1"^^xsd:int, "2"^^xsd:int, "3"^^xsd:int, "4"^^xsd:int}`

This should do the trick.

Note: there's a bug in Protege 5 beta 21 that will not make this work. Either use Protege 5 beta 17 or wait for the next beta for this to work properly.